# Null values seem to produce incorrect data in a foreach loop

Tags: powershell, null

I have several examples of this but I have found that if an iteration in a foreach loop returns a Null vale, or is nonexistent, it propagates the previous iteration’s value.

For example, here I am trying to get the default browser details on a group of remote machines:

```
$Results = foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $User = $computer -Replace '\D*\d*(\w*)', '$1'
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Server server.com -Identity $User -Properties *
    $CompProps = Get-ADComputer -Server servercom -Identity $Computer

    $SID = (Get-ADUser -Server server.com -Identity $User).SID.Value

    $ComputerName = "$Computer"
    $Hive = 'Users'

    $KeyPath = "$SID\Software\Microsoft\windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice"
    $Value = 'Progid'
    $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("$hive", "$ComputerName")
    $key = $reg.OpenSubKey("$KeyPath")
    $Browser = $key.GetValue($Value)

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        FullName       = $ADUser.Name
        UserName       = $ADUser.SamAccountName
        Computer       = $CompProps.Name
        DefaultBrowser = switch ($Browser) {
            'ChromeHTML' { Write-Output "Google Chrome" }
            'IE.HTTP' { Write-Output "Internet Explorer" }
            'AppXq0fevzme2pys62n3e0fbqa7peapykr8v' { Write-Output "Microsoft Edge" }
        }
    }
}
$Results
```

When the results come out, as soon as there is a computer without the registry path "$SID\Software\Microsoft\windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice", it repeats the last value.

Why is that and what can I do to circumvent that?

Comment: Hi Vivek, I tried that, no luck unfortunately. Its the browser name that it gets wrong as soon as it hits a machine that does not have the correct registry path.

Comment: I do not agree which @VivekKumarSingh, the synyax you using is correct and will return *all* objects as an array. I presume that you are suppressing errors as `$key.GetValue($Value)` should produce an error as you can't run a method on a `$Null`, consequently the `$Browser` value will not be replaced. To avoid this, just add an `If ($Key) {...` before this line.

Comment: Thanks iRon, if you could be more specific about  just add an If ($Key) {..." that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

When you save values to a variable, the variable will maintain the value until told otherwise. In essence when you reach a computer without a value in your loop the variable won't be updated and it'll take the previous value in use.

To get around this you could wrap your code inside the loop in an if statement

```
$User = $computer -Replace '\D*\d*(\w*)', '$1'
$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Server server.com -Identity $User -Properties * 
$CompProps = Get-ADComputer -Server servercom -Identity $Computer 


$SID = (Get-ADUser -server server.com -Identity $User).SID.Value 


$ComputerName = "$Computer"
$Hive = 'Users'

$KeyPath = "$SID\Software\Microsoft\windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice" 
$Value = 'Progid'
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("$hive", "$ComputerName") 
$key = $reg.OpenSubKey("$KeyPath") 
$Browser = $key.GetValue($Value) 

if($keypath -neq $keypathprevious)
{
[PSCustomObject]@{
     FullName          = $ADUser.Name
     UserName          = $ADUser.SamAccountName
     Computer          = $CompProps.Name 
     DefaultBrowser    = Switch ($Browser) {

                    'ChromeHTML' { Write-Output "Google Chrome" }
                    'IE.HTTP' { Write-Output "Internet Explorer" }
                    'AppXq0fevzme2pys62n3e0fbqa7peapykr8v' { Write-Output "Microsoft Edge" }

                }
$keypathprevious = $keypath
}
else
{
write-host "error"
}
}
```

At least this way you shouldn't run into repeats of a previous result.
I'm sure someone else has a prettier way of working this out, but this is what I could think of looking at your code.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I refactored the code as you describe but now I just get "error" the same number of times as there computers in the collection. I will go through it again to see why that is, but I get what you're saying.

Comment: Try to change it to
    elseif($keypath -eq $keypathprevious)

Comment: @IanB Another option to make sure you don't repeat the values of the previous loop would be to add a clear-variable -name "X/Y/Z" at the bottom of your foreach loop. That way the variables are dropped for every iteration and won't be repeated. In this case you could add Clear-variable -name "Browser" or clear-variable -name "Keypath".
Then change the if to if($browser){"your code"} and change the else to else($browser -eq null){write-host "Path missing"}
I'm not sure this solves your entire problem, but I'm just spitballing ideas to get to a more permanent solution.

Comment: You should keep the try{} from @Theo

Comment: BINGO!!!!! Thanks Simon, and thanks everyone here. In the end, simply adding Clear-variable -name Browser at the end of the loop worked perfectly. This is a technique I can use in other saces likt this that I have, so simple yet very effective. THANKS! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have tidied up your code a bit and added a `try{..} catch{..}` block, because reading registry values on remote machines can error out for various reasons.

Like Simon Bøgelund I have added a test to only add a new PSCustomObject to the results if you actually found something.

**Important I think:** When opening registry keys, always clean-up by closing them again after you have finished using them.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
# the $Computers is an array of remote machine names

$Results = @()
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    # don't know what the $Computers list contains, but.. is this correct?
    $User      = $computer -Replace '\D*\d*(\w*)', '$1'          
    # these properties are returned by default for Get-ADUser: 
    # DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName
    $ADUser    = Get-ADUser -Server server.com -Identity $User   
    $CompProps = Get-ADComputer -Server server.com -Identity $Computer 
    $SID       = $ADUser.SID.Value 
    $KeyPath   = "$SID\Software\Microsoft\windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice" 

    try {
        $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("Users", $Computer) 
        $key = $reg.OpenSubKey($KeyPath) 
        $Browser = $key.GetValue('Progid') 

        if ($Browser) {
            $Results += [PSCustomObject]@{
                 FullName       = $ADUser.Name
                 UserName       = $ADUser.SamAccountName
                 Computer       = $CompProps.Name 
                 DefaultBrowser = Switch ($Browser) {
                                        'ChromeHTML'                           { "Google Chrome" }
                                        'IE.HTTP'                              { "Internet Explorer" }
                                        'AppXq0fevzme2pys62n3e0fbqa7peapykr8v' { "Microsoft Edge" }
                                     }
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Could not open registry key on computer $computer. Reason: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
    finally {
        # close the registry keys when done!
        if ($key) { $key.Close() }
        if ($reg) { $reg.Close() }
    }
}

$Results
```

Comment: Hi Theo, thank you the highly detailed reply. I tried that exactly only adding the $Computers source which in an AD fetch returning 10 machines. What I found with that is that it returns all 10 machines as "WARNING: Could not open registry key on computer BLAHBLAH. Reason: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." when most do actually have the correct registry path. The second thing I found was it took a very very long time to complete, my original code took about 30 seconds to complete albeit with bad Browser results. Not sure why that is? Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: @IanB Difficult to say.. Are you running this as user with enough permissions on the remote machines? At what line does it break ?(on `$reg =..`, or on `$key = ..` ? Are all machines reachable (that could account for slow response)?. Maybe we should put in a `if (!(Test-Connection $Computer -count 1 -quiet)) { Write-Warning "Computer $Computer is off-line" ; continue }` right below the `ForEach` line.